# Get free space in current folder

Tags: java, nio, java-8

I have this Java code which gets the HDD and RAM space and checks the available free space. For some reason its not working properly in Linux. I see every time the warning message. How I can get the free space of the current folder where I'm running the Java code?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

public final class EnvironmentCheck{

    public EnvironmentCheck(){

        // If the HDD Free Space is less than 200 Megabytes write message HDD is too low
        if (200 > checkHDDFreeSpace()){
            System.out.println("*** WARNING Hard Drive free space " + checkHDDFreeSpace() + " Megabytes " + "is too low! ***");
            // TODO write the same messgae into the log file
        }

        // If the RAM Free Space is less than 200 Megabytes write message HDD is too low
        if (200 > checkRAMFreeSpace()){
            System.out.println("*** WARNING RAM free space " + checkRAMFreeSpace() + " Megabytes " + "is too low! ***");
            // TODO write the same messgae into the log file
        }

    }

    /**
    * Get available HDD Free space from the system
    *
    * @return
    */
    public long checkHDDFreeSpace(){

        long availableSpace = 0;

        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores()){

            try{
                availableSpace = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
                //System.out.println(availableSpace);
            }catch (IOException e){

            }
        }
        return availableSpace;
    }

    /**
    * Get available RAM Free memory
    *
    * @return
    */
    public long checkRAMFreeSpace(){
        return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }

}
```

Comment: You wrote `get the free space of the current folder`. As a folder has no space limit (by default), this might only be possible for whole partitions. Just to be uber-correct ;)

Comment: "I see every time the warning message"  - What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I suspect it is the warning he generates himself, the one on `if (200 > checkHDDFreeSpace()){`.

Comment: Yes, how I can get the free space of the partition where the code is running?

Comment: I don't think `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` is doing what you think it's doing. It gives the amount of free memory in the JVM, not in the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to find out the free space of the partition ( mount mount ) where your folder is located.
You are getting the warning message because you are overwriting the `avaialableSpace` variable in each iteration

```
for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores()){
    try{
            //gets overwritten in each iteration, hence you get the
            //warning every time
            availableSpace = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
            //System.out.println(availableSpace);
        }catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

First try to locate the `FileStore` corresponding to your directory ( for e.g it can be `/usr/home` for `/usr/home/foouser` and then get the size of that FileStore only

Comment: This might help you [FileStoreExample](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk7/files-getfileattributeview-files-getfilestore-java-nio)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest first you try to get the total available memory and then subtract the usable memory .

You can try :-

```
for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores()){
    try{
            long totalSpace=  store.getTotalSpace();
            long usableSpace=  store.getUsableSpace();
            availableSpace = (totalSpace - usableSpace) / 1024;
        }catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.